# How to show a disabled checkbox on a treenode

Tags: asp.net, treeview

Im using an asp.net TreeView that is constructed on server side? 
how can i disable a check box on a tree node but still show it?

tks

Comment: are you trying to disable all check boxes or just a select few? Either ways, you might have to use javascript (jQuery would make it much easier) as the TreeNode does not seem to have anything like "Enabled".

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no way server-side purely that I have seen that will disable the checkboxes once rendered on the client using an ASP.NET TreeView control. One of the better solutions I have seen is to add a `className` attribute server-side and then scan the checkboxes client-side for the class and disable. This actually is not too bad of a method and it works well.

The `className` is acting as a flag for client-side code to disable the checkbox. Client side JavaScript *can* disable the checkbox which is actually just an HTML `input`.

Have a look at the following example which has the server-side code and client-side JavaScript example on how to do this: [Disabling ASP.net treeview checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15078476/disabling-asp-net-treeview-checkboxes)

Answer (score 1):

¿What about adding an input checkbox to the text of the treenode and set ShowCheckBox = False?

ex:

```
If NotEnabled Then
  TreeNodeSDM.ShowCheckBox = False
  TreeNodeSDM.SelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.None
  Dim cChecked As String = ""
  If bChecked Then cChecked = "checked='checked'"
  TreeNodeSDM.Text = "<input type='checkbox' disabled='disabled' " & cChecked & "><font 
  color='GRAY'>" & TreeNodeSDM.Text & "</font>"
End If
```

Answer (score -1):

Call the jQuery function from server side, in your jQuery function disable the checkboxes.