# Convert Scanning For className JavaScript block to use jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, treeview

I have a small block I wanted to convert to using jQuery for a couple of different purposes, but mainly to reverse engineer how it works to imporve my jQuery skills. I tried taking a go at it, but could not figure out all of the conversions.

The following `Javascript` block iterated through the checkboxes rendered in an ASP.NET TreeView control client-side and scan for checkboxes with a `className=disabledTreeviewNode` (this equivilent functionality *cannot* be achieved purely server side).

```
  function DisableCheckBoxes(treeviewClientID) {

     var treeView = document.getElementById(treeviewClientID);       
     if (treeView) {

        //Get all the checkboxes which are 'inputs' in the treeview
        var childCheckBoxes = treeView.getElementsByTagName("input");

        //Iterate through the checkboxes and disable any checkbox that has a className="disabledTreeviewNode"
        for (var i = 0; i < childCheckBoxes.length; i++) {

           var textSpan = childCheckBoxes[i].parentNode.getElementsByTagName("span")[0];
           if (textSpan != null && textSpan.firstChild)
              if (textSpan.className == "disabledTreeviewNode" || textSpan.firstChild.className == "disabledTreeviewNode")
                 childCheckBoxes[i].disabled = true;
        }
     }
  }
```

I tried changing the following:

```
var treeView = document.getElementById(treeviewClientID);
```

to

```
var treeView = $('#' + treeviewClientID);
```

However then I could no longer call `getElementsByTagName`. I tried to use the jQuery equivilent of `.find` but then the code started to behave differently and I was a bit lost.

Can anyone assist on converting this small block to use jQuery? Comments are welcome as to if this is worthwhile or even if there is a better way.

**EDIT:** This `class=disabledTreeviewNode` is assigned server-side like this:

```
tn.Text = "<span class=disabledTreeviewNode>" + tn.Text + "</span>";
```

It's a bit of a hack/flag so that client-side code can read it and set it's *parent* which is the checkbox to `disabled`. Why the Parent? I can't directly set the class on the checkbox in code because that property is not accessible. The hack: set the `TreeView` object's `.Text` to have the `<span class=disabledTreeviewNode>` value and then set it's parent (the checkbox) to disabled client-side.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/24WqX/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many of the jQuery object's methods call `.each()` method behind the scene, so you don't have to iterate through the collection, jQuery does this for you.

```
$('#' + treeviewClientID + ' input').filter(function() {
     return $(this.parentNode).find('.disabledTreeviewNode').length;
}).prop('disabled', true);
```

Comment: Awesome!! This worked perfectly and no `undefined` errors or anything :P So breaking it down I see you get the jQuery object representing the treeview, get the parent node, ensure it has the `disabledTreeviewNode` via length (would not of thought to use `length` here) and set the `diabled` property to `true. That about right?

Comment: @atconway Yes, that's correct, Slaks's code also should work if you remove the `span` from the selector, but I prefer using the `.filter()` method, in most cases it is faster than inefficient selectors.

Comment: This doesn't quite replicate the code in the question, but that code may have more constraints than necessary. It would be better if OP posted the markup.

Comment: @user2736012 - The code used honestly was probably a bit suspect and may have not been a perfect implementation, and that's why I provided some background. In a nutshell, find the class named `disabledTreeviewNode` and set that element to disabled. The code I posted was probably a bit verbose to begin with, based off of this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15078476/disabling-asp-net-treeview-checkboxes.

Comment: @atconway: In that case, it could just be done like this: *(trying to force code to the next line)* `$('#'+treeviewClientID+' input.disabledTreeviewNode').prop("disabled", true)`. This also seems to be what the comment in your code suggests.

Comment: I added an **EDIT* to my OP that may clarify why the 'Parent' must be sought out. I can't just blindly set the 'disabled' to true because the actual `input` checkbox does not have that value; it's the parent of the `span`.

Comment: @undefined - You code is perfect, but is there a way to not only seek out the parent and set `disabled = true` (like you already have) but also the actual element (the label with text next to the checkbox in my case) to have `disabled=true` as well?

Comment: @atconway: You really should be posting a sample of your HTML when you're asking about DOM traversal. We're having to interpret what your DOM is like based on a code solution that acknowledge is suspect.

Comment: @atconway Does this mean you want to add `disabled` attribute to label elements? Labels don't have `disabled` attribute. What about adding a class? `.prop(...).next('label').addClass('disabled')`?

Comment: @undefined your right. I had to inspect the page & that server control was turning the label into a `<a>` hyperlink. I just didn't want to have it clickable. I was able to solve it by setting `SelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.None` server-side. One anomaly I'm trying to figure out (old JS & your new code behave the same) is if I double-click the disabled checkbox really fast it actually works. Single-click slow, it is disabled. On mouse hover it shows disabled, but double-clicking fast is still allowing some click action - I just need to dig in and figure out. Regardless, your code rocked!

Comment: @undefined - looks like my wired up client-side `onclick` function for the tree is still allowed to be called even though the checkbox is disabled: `onclick="OnTreeClick(event)"`. I can probably bypass this so the code does not run.

Comment: @atconway Glad to have been of help. Please avoid using `onclick` attribute, specially when you are using jQuery, in your handler you can check the `disabled` property and prevent the execution of the next lines if it's `disabled`, `if (this.disabled) return;`

Comment: That was exactly what I did and it worked well! All complete :)

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#' + treeviewClientID + ' span:has(.disabledTreeviewNode) input')
    .prop('disabled', true);
```

Comment: Well I got super excited because this looks *slick* but it is not working. There is no JS error, it just doesn't disable. However I'm inspecting the page to see if it took and if there is any issue on my end. The code I posted _does_ work and reading yours looks like it should.

Comment: My edit on the OP probably helps explain why for my particular example it was important to seek out the parent for setting the `disabled` property. Thanks for your help.